# Bootstrap select: selecting options using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to select the already selected options via jquery, however the black `tick` isn't visible:

[image]

Tried selecting it:

```
$('.skills :last').find('option:contains("Calculating data")').prop('selected', true);
[option]

$('.skills :last').val();
["Calculating data↵"]

$('.skills');
[div.btn-group.bootstrap-select.show-tick.skills.job-seeker-content-spacing, select.selectpicker.skills.job-seeker-content-spacing]

$('.skills :first').find('option:contains("Calculating data")').prop('selected', true);
[option]

$('.skills :first').val();
""
```

also tried with `click`, on the shell it shows it's been selected but doesn't show the select on the site example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text :

`var text = $('.skills').find(":selected").text();`

If you want the value :

`var value = $('.skills').find(":selected").val();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about bootstrap-select but after some digging into it, I fount a way,

after you call

```
$('.skills :last').find('option:contains("Calculating data")').prop('selected', true);
```

The option get selected and works properly,

let's assume the select tag has #selecting id,

now call this to refresh bootstrap-select to get that tick,

```
$("#selecting").data("selectpicker").refresh()
```